# Cast from 'void *' to 'const std::string *&' must have all intermediate pointers const qualified

Tags: c++, casting, clang

I have this piece of code which uses iostreams' `xalloc` and `pword` to store flags of various types as pointers.  Since `pword` exposes a `void*&`, I have a simple wrapper to expose the stored type via an old C cast.  But since its version 5, clang issues a warning that I don't understand well.  I don't see how to avoid it.  The simple test case looks as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std::literals;

void*& pword()
{
  static void* ptr;
  return ptr;
}

const std::string*& sword()
{
  return (const std::string*&) pword();
}

int main()
{
  const auto s1 = "foo"s;
  const auto s2 = "bar"s;
  sword() = &s1;
  std::cerr << *sword() << '\n';
  sword() = &s2;
  std::cerr << *sword() << '\n';
}
```

The warnings I get (which seem to forget the reference on `void*`):

```
clang++-mp-devel -std=c++17 -Wcast-qual foo.cc && ./a.out 
foo.cc:14:32: warning: cast from 'void *' to 'const std::string *&' (aka 'const basic_string<char,
      char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > *&') must have all intermediate pointers const qualified
      to be safe [-Wcast-qual]
  return (const std::string*&) pword();
                               ^
1 warning generated.
foo
bar
```

Also, I fail to see how to use C++ casts instead of the C almighty cast.  Obvious attempts:

```
const std::string*& sword2()
{
  return static_cast<const std::string*&>(pword());
}
```

end with errors I don't understand.  The error seems to give a hint that the compiler might feel obliged to insert a copy somewhere, breaking the chain of references, but I don't see where and why.

```
foo.cc:19:10: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'const std::string *' (aka 'const
      basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > *') cannot bind to a value of
      unrelated type 'void *'
  return static_cast<const std::string*&>(pword());
         ^                                ~~~~~~~
```

Comment: The right cast here is `reinterpret_cast`, not `static_cast`.

Comment: If you want to return a reference from a function, the first thing you need is an object that outlives the function call. Where is such an object in your code?

Comment: @n.m. In pword.

Comment: `pword` is a function, not an object.

Comment: @n.m.: And it defines a static variable `ptr` that outlives it, as required.

Comment: Sorry didnt't see the static variable somehow, please disregard my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to the famous fact that you can’t convert `char**` to `const char**`—because it would allow

```
const char cc='a';
const char *cp=&cc;
char *p;
const char **pp=&p;  // error in question
*pp=cp;  // i.e., p=&cc;
*p='z';  // oops
```

In this case, by describing a `void*` as a `const std::string*`, you can store pointers to constant strings there (like you do) and then use a `static_cast` on the `void*` to obtain a non-`const` pointer to the string.

The answer is to use `const_cast` to *add* `const` and then (as HolyBlackCat said) `reinterpret_cast` (and then be careful not to try modifying the strings!):

```
const std::string*& sword()
{
  return reinterpret_cast<const std::string*&>(const_cast<const void*&>(pword()));
}
```

Aside from const-correctness, I do not remember definitively at the moment whether storing a `T*` into a `void*` variable via such a `reinterpret_cast` is defined behavior; it is, however, something one expects to work in common implementations.

Comment: Thanks for providing a rationale to this behaviour!